# Indeterminate progress bar like iPhone GMAIL app in android

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I want to make indeterminate progress bar like iPhone GMAIL app in android.As attached below with animation.

EDIT :: In android is it possible to have animation [like][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/library/pure/4547132/`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You have the spinner in the palette (see the image attached below). I think it´s similar to what you want. But if you want to  make this progress bar using this exactly image, you can add the image and using animation make it rotate.

Hope it´s useful!!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not I wanted. In android is it possible to have animation like http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/library/pure/4547132/